# Moodle 2.2 and oauth web app client Id not working

Tags: oauth-2.0

Trying to setup Moodle 2.2 with Google Drive Repository so Moodle students can upload their Google Docs into Moodle assignments.

Using google developers console I have created a Web Application Client ID and added it to Moodle's Google Repository settings.

When File Picker comes up for Moodle users trying to submit assignments Google Drive repository is available. When clicked on they get a Login button. Clicking login button opens an empty folder on Google Drive. They aren't asked for their own login credentials.

Have I made the correct type of API Client ID.
OR is there something else needed?

I did also Save the Consent Screen in the Google Project API.
Thanks in advance,
Shirley

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have entered the 'Authorized Redirect URI' exactly as shown on your Google Drive plugin config page in Moodle (copy and paste to make sure).

You should also make sure 'Drive API' is enabled on the API page of the Google Dev Console.

If both of these are already set correctly, you could try turning on developer level debugging in Moodle (if it isn't already) and see if that gives you any helpful debug messages when you try again.

Hope this helps.